# Google Play is putting adds up when I'm doing anything on my phone. text, games, gallery etc

Tags: google-play-store, google

When I open my text message and start to reply to the friend. Google play opens with an Android add. I hit the back button and it takes me to Google play home. So then I have to back out. When your in the middle of typing it's really annoying... any ideas what to do??

Comment: I am very sure it's not Google Play that is annoying you with ads, but rather another app opening a Google Play URL, that is automatically picked up by Google Play.

Comment: What text app are you using? Most likely the culprit, not Google Play store -  IMO they have other ways of annoying you. Did you look at the permissions that it has (when installing text app)?

Comment: Absolutely this is adware from an app you have installed. What SMS app are you using? Have you sideloaded anything lately? Have you installed any dodgy apps. It might be time for some spring cleaning to find the offending app.